# Derivative of a Dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

When taking the $\frac{\partial{\hat{y}}}{\partial{\mathbf{V}}}$ where $\hat{y}$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, how do I calculate the gradient where:

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{y} &= \mathbf{W}\mathbf{h_t^T}; \mathbf{W,h_t} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\\
\mathbf{h_t} &= \mathscr{O} \odot \theta; \mathscr{O},\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\\
\mathscr{O} &= \operatorname{\sigma}(\mathbf{V}\mathbf{h_{t-1}^T}); 
\end{align}
$$

Where $\sigma$ is just the vector version of the expit/sigmoid function.

Comment: Your dimensions don't work for $W$. Or perhaps you meant to write $$y=W^T\cdot h_t$$ Also $\frac{\partial y}{\partial V_3}$ is the gradient of a vector with respect to a matrix, which is a 3rd-order tensor not a matrix.  Unless you meant vectorize the matrix, e.g. $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial {\rm vec}(V_3)} = h^T_{t-1}\otimes(WR(Q-Q^2))$$ where $$\eqalign{R &= {\rm Diag}(\theta)\cr Q &= {\rm Diag}(\sigma)\cr}$$Hmm, I can't get mathscr(O) to work in the comment,so I used a sigma.

Comment: Just got it worked out.  This isn't really correct.  The diagonals are adding in terms when you multiply through.